# Visual Fox Pro - List Method

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am new to Visual Fox Pro (VFP) and it's hard to find what I need documentation wise.

I am trying to understand what this means:

```
lcServiceWhere = ThisForm.cboNoteType.List[ThisForm.cboNoteType.ListIndex,3]
```

Is this taking the 3rd value (so index = 2) in a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of Foxpro code uses Hungarian notation for naming variables.

Based on common naming standards, `cboNoteType` is mostly likely a Combobox control. The `List` property is an array of the contents of the combobox. The `ListIndex` is the currently selected row. The 3 represents the 3rd column in that array.

So the `lcServiceWhere` variable is being assigned the value in 3rd column of the currently the selected row of (the array that's holding) the contents of the `cboNoteType` Combobox.

Answer (score 0):

ListIndex denote the selected item's index and 3 is the column number. This type of retrieval always returns the data as string regardless of the underlying datatype.